# Maven (Eclipse plugin and mvn) not including main class with pom.xml setup

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin

I've been trying to work this out for the last few hours and I've got nowhere. I've just installed the Maven for Eclipse plugin (M2E, I think) and also the maven too, mvn. I've created a very simple Hello World project and am trying to get the built jar to run on using:
java -jar pimidi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Regardless of what I try, I always get the same error:
no main manifest attribute, in target/pimidi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dan</groupId>
    <artifactId>pimidi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>pimidi</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.dan.pimidi.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I've tried countless different options within the manifest nodes of the POM (classpath, manifest location), different plugins (assembly, compile, etc) to no avail. On looking at the effective POM in Eclipse, I can see that maven-jar-plugin is already included from a higher-level POM an any changes to the project POM are omitted.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to get this working? Apologies if this question lacks detail - I have expired my mental power for this evening. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the contents of `target/pimidi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.  Is there a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file?  And if yes, does that file contain a `Main-Class: com.dan.pimidi.App` attribute?

Comment: It does now - managed to fix it yesterday :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After following numerous pieces of advice, I decided to delete my project (which was only a mvn archetype), uninstall eclipse (to remove the m2e plugin) along with my ~/.m2 folder. I then did everything from the command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.dan.pimidi -DartifactId=pimidi -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Added this to my pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                                <archive>
                                        <manifest>
                                                <mainClass>com.dan.pimidi.App</mainClass>
                                        </manifest>
                                </archive>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Then a quick:

```
mvn clean package
```

And a:

```
java -jar target/nameofjar.jar
```

Solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running:

> mvn clean install exec:java

In the same folder as your pom.xml (from the root of your project)?

Comment: I get the following, along with a few more generic error lines - any ideas?  `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project pimidi: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]`  - I'll have more chance to investigate later; will also speak to people in work to see if they can help.